# iMacros: How do I change the content of text with a var?

Tags: imacros

I am pretty new to it and I can't find an answer to this.

So how do I change the text inside the text area?

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:mdeform ATTR=NAME:title CONTENT=sampletext
```

I want the macro to edit sampletext to mytext. How do I do that?

I also have another question.

The CONTENT will contain "part1.mp4"
How do I change it to "My video: part1"? 
So basically the extension needs to get removed and some words will be added.
I thought about storing "My video" in a constant and then ".mp4" needs to get removed. (a constant because "My video" stays the same, only "part1" will be a different word each time.
How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SET myText My<SP>video:<SP>
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:mdeform ATTR=NAME:title EXTRACT=TXT
SET sampleText EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/\.mp4/,\"\")")
ADD myText {{sampleText}}
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:mdeform ATTR=NAME:title CONTENT={{myText}}
```